# Can i use Sqlite database in my WP7 applicaton

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-7

Please any on tell me can i use Sqlite database in my Windows Phone 7.1 application

Comment: I have already database in sqlite that use in android and iphone...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find solutions both [from here](http://www.wirebear.com/blog/2010/11/12/using-sqlite-in-your-wp7-app/) and from [here](http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.com/2010/07/wp7-sqliteclient-with-transaction.html)

For the record there is a client for win phone 7 on CodePlex as mentioned in the first article and that is [here](http://sqlitewindowsphone.codeplex.com/)

If you do not require (and by require mean it's IMPOSSIBLE not to change it because of a requirement)

there is an alternative to SQLite which is [here](http://sterling.codeplex.com/) called Sterling.

The excerpt from the sterling site says:

> "Sterling is a lightweight NoSQL object-oriented database for .Net
>   4.0, Silverlight 4 and 5, and Windows Phone 7 that works with your existing class structures. Sterling supports full LINQ to Object
>   queries over keys and indexes for fast retrieval of information from
>   large data sets."